# How to sort an array based on one property and then group by another property in React Redux application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, underscore.js, reducers

I'm trying to manipulate data received from an API, it requires grouping according to the `category` like `country`, `city` and `state` based on their `display_priority`. Also, sort similar category items based on their `display_priority`. I did try using JS functions and also with `lodash` library, but couldn't get the desired output.
API response:

```
[
    {
        "category": {
            "name": "country",
            "display_priority": 1
        },
        "name": "US",
        "display_priority": 2,
        "enabled": false
    },
    {
        "category": {
            "name": "city",
            "display_priority": 3
        },
        "name": "Greenville",
        "display_priority": 1,
        "enabled": true
    },
    {
        "category": {
            "name": "state",
            "display_priority": 2
        },
        "name": "Alabama",
        "display_priority": 2,
        "enabled": true
    },
    {
        "category": {
            "name": "state",
            "display_priority": 2
        },
        "name": "Arizona",
        "display_priority": 1,
        "enabled": false
    },
    {
        "category": {
            "name": "city",
            "display_priority": 3
        },
        "name": "Houston",
        "display_priority": 2,
        "enabled": false
    },
    {
        "category": {
            "name": "country",
            "display_priority": 1
        },
        "name": "Germany",
        "display_priority": 1,
        "enabled": true
    }
]
```

Required output:

```
[
{
   "category": "country",
   "list": [
      {
         "name": "Germany",
         "enabled": true
      },
      {
         "name": "US",
         "enabled": false
      }
   ]
},
{
   "category": "state",
   "list": [
      {
         "name": "Arizona",
         "enabled": false
      },
      {
         "name": "Alabama",
         "enabled": true
      }
   ]
},
{
   "category": "city",
   "list": [
      {
         "name": "Greenville",
         "enabled": true
      },
      {
         "name": "Houston",
         "enabled": false
      }
   ]
}]
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could more clearly state the rules for how the algorithm works. But whatever they are, some mix of  `.sort`, `.filter`, and `.reduce` will likely be needed. It would be helpful if you showed what you have tried.

Comment: @MatthewHerbst I tried this code 

    `var grouped = _.groupBy(data, 'category.display_priority');
     const keys = Object.keys(grouped);
     for (const key of keys) {
         grouped[key] = _.sortBy(grouped[key], 'display_priority');
     }
     console.log('newArray', Object.values(grouped));`

Answer (score 1):

You can easily get this result with a single [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and object destructuring:

```js
const data = [{ "category": { "name": "country", "display_priority": 1 }, "name": "US", "display_priority": 2, "enabled": false }, { "category": { "name": "city", "display_priority": 3 }, "name": "Greenville", "display_priority": 1, "enabled": true }, { "category": { "name": "state", "display_priority": 2 }, "name": "Alabama", "display_priority": 2, "enabled": true }, { "category": { "name": "state", "display_priority": 2 }, "name": "Arizona", "display_priority": 1, "enabled": false }, { "category": { "name": "city", "display_priority": 3 }, "name": "Houston", "display_priority": 2, "enabled": false }, { "category": { "name": "country", "display_priority": 1 }, "name": "Germany", "display_priority": 1, "enabled": true } ]

const result = data.reduce((accumulator, {category, name, enabled}) => {
  let key = category.name
  accumulator[key] = accumulator[key] || { category: key, list: [] }
  accumulator[key].list.push({name, enabled})
  return accumulator
}, {})
console.log(Object.values(result))
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, but this does not consider `display_priority` which is basically the order in which category array and list array will be sorted.